# Add a \cmidrule and I get an illegal parameter number in definition

Tags: tables, xetex

When I add a \cmidrule into a table and then try to recompile in XeLatex, it breaks.

It stops at the \begin{document}:

```
File ended while scanning definition of \LT@xxxix. \begin{document}
Illegal parameter number in definition of \LT@xxxix. \begin{document}
Illegal parameter number in definition of \LT@xxxix. \begin{document}
File ended while scanning definition of \LT@xxxix.
```

I fix it by deleting the .aux file, and it works again as long as I do not add in a \cmidrule.

I am a noob to LaTeX, so any help is appreciated.

This is where it stops:

```
   ...
    Chapter 7.
    ! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
    <template> \endtemplate

    l.1204 ^^I\cmidrule(r){3-8}

    ?

    Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active [29]
    [30]
    Appendix A.
```

This is my preamble:

```
    \documentclass{book}
    \usepackage[letterpaper,inner=0.75in,outer=1in]{geometry}
    \usepackage{color}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{longtable,booktabs}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{parskip} %removes firstline indent
    \usepackage{makeidx}
    \usepackage{titling}
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
```

Example of table:

```
\begin{longtable}[]{@{}llll@{}}
    \toprule
    centeral & personal & &\tabularnewline
    \cmidrule(r){3-8}
    \endhead
    & reflexive & &\tabularnewline
    & possessive & &\tabularnewline
    reciprocal & each other, one another & &\tabularnewline
    relative & & &\tabularnewline
    interrogative & & &\tabularnewline
    demonstrative & this, that, these, those & &\tabularnewline
    Indefinite & positive & universal & All, both\tabularnewline
    & & & Each, every\tabularnewline
    & & assertive & some\tabularnewline
    & & & Multal, paucal\tabularnewline
    & & & One\tabularnewline
    & & & Half, several, enough\tabularnewline
    & & & Other, another\tabularnewline
    & & nonassertive & Any, either\tabularnewline
    & negative & & No, neither\tabularnewline
    \bottomrule
\end{longtable}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome. Can you show the actual code of the table as well?

Comment: I added it to the main question, but it happens with every table I try. thanks

Answer (score 6):

Your table has four columns, but you've asked the `\cmidrule` to span columns 3 to 8. That doesn't work. I don't know exactly which columns you intended  it to span, but `\cmidrule(r){3-4}` for example works.

You might want just `\midrule` though:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[letterpaper,inner=0.75in,outer=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}[]{@{}llll@{}}
\toprule
centeral & personal & &\tabularnewline
\midrule
\endhead
& reflexive & &\tabularnewline
& possessive & &\tabularnewline
reciprocal & each other, one another & &\tabularnewline
relative & & &\tabularnewline
interrogative & & &\tabularnewline
demonstrative & this, that, these, those & &\tabularnewline
Indefinite & positive & universal & All, both\tabularnewline
& & & Each, every\tabularnewline
& & assertive & some\tabularnewline
& & & Multal, paucal\tabularnewline
& & & One\tabularnewline
& & & Half, several, enough\tabularnewline
& & & Other, another\tabularnewline
& & nonassertive & Any, either\tabularnewline
& negative & & No, neither\tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ahh, so If I do not have the right columns indicated it will break the table? It does work now. Thanks.

Comment: @esponapule Well, yes (apparently).

Comment: well, I meant it would not even compile instead of producing a wrong result within the table. It would not even create the PDF where as other errors would create a PDF but the table would be a mess.

Comment: @esponapule I don't actually get the same error as you, but I could skip through them and get a PDF. But I cannot shed any more light on that bit.